# Row Delete in table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

my whole code is this, but my code has one error and not run:
read from file is correctly , but dont delet row.

```
public class AllUserTable extends AbstractTableModel{

Vector data;
Vector columns;
public AllUserTable() {

        String line;
        data = new Vector();
        columns = new Vector();
        try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\AllUserRecords.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
      StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");
              while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
               columns.addElement(st1.nextToken());
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                       StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                        while (st2.hasMoreTokens())
                                data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                }
                br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size() / getColumnCount();
}

public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.size();
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return (String) data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount())
                        + columnIndex);
}

  public static void main(String[] args){

    final AllUserTable aut1=new AllUserTable();
    final JFrame frame1=new JFrame();
    final JTable table=new JTable();
    final JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JButton button1=new JButton("Delete");

     button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(data,columns);  //Error!
            model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
            table.setModel(model);
            table.setModel(aut1);
            panel.add(table);
        }
    });

    JScrollPane scroolpane=new JScrollPane();
    scroolpane.setViewportView(table);
    panel.add(scroolpane);
    panel.add(button1);
    frame1.add(panel);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setBounds(200, 80, 600, 500);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

please repair my code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code doesn't compile. You're referencing instance fields (`data`, `columns`) from a static method (main). The error message of the compiler should tell you that. And if you don't understand it, googling for the error message should lead you to explanations of the error message.

And even if it did compiler, here's an explanation of each line of the event listener:

```
DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(data,columns);
```

Create a new table model. Why? Your table already has one. All you need is to modify the existing table model

```
model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
```

Remove a row from this new table model. Why modify a new model instead of modifying the existing one?

```
        table.setModel(model);
```

Replace the old model by a new one. This is very inefficient. The table already has a model. Modify it.

```
        table.setModel(aut1);
```

Replace the new model by the old one. Why?

```
        panel.add(table);
```

Add the table to the main panel of the frame. Why? The table is already there and visible. This makes no sense.

You should implement a `deleteRow()` method in your AbstractTableModel.

Using a List of objects, where each row represents a row, would also be much clearer than using a single list to represent all the rows.

I have the feeling that you're copying and pasting code without understanding at all how it works and what the architecture of Swing is. Read the Swing tutorial. And even before that, read an introductory book about Java, variables and scopes.

Comment: Thank you, Are You Prefer Special Book For Me?

Comment: No. I learnt all this many years ago, and I now use the tutorial and the javadoc as primary sources of information.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you never set the table model (`aut1`) to the table BEFORE your button action.

Secondly, I don't see where data and `columns` are defined when you construct the new `DefaultTableModel` in your action handler - the you try and delete a row from this "new" table model and the apply it to the table and then replace to with `aut1`, which effectively has done....nothing.

When constructing your UI, don't forget to set the table model to the table ... `table.setModel(aut1)`

Remove the `DefaultTableModel` from the action handler and use `aut1` instead.

**Updated with suggestions**

- You should avoid constructing your UI in the `static main` method, instead use a class instance instead, it will make you code cleaner and will present less issues into the future
- You should only ever construct/manipulate UI/Swing components from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, use `EventQueue#invokeLater`